# formatted cell value not equal to cell value even if it is because of formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having DataGridView with column with this formatting property `dataGridView1.Columns["RABAT"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0\\%";`

So when I step into cell and exit it my `dataGridView1_CellValidating` event fires up. There I have simple check where I check if old value of that cell is equal to new value and if it is then do not proceed with code and it looks like this

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value == e.FormattedValue)
    return;
```

Now problem is that because of formatting property for `dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value` I get returned `10` but as `e.FormattedValue` I get returned `10%` and it passes this check since these two values are not same.

What I can do (and know how to do) is remove everything but numbers from `e.FormattedValue` and then compare since in this case there are only ints in this column but for future code how can I remove format style from `e.FormattedValue`?

I have done it this way but it is temporary since I have a lot of columns and do not want to create each time other method for getting rid of format.

```
switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
{
    case "KOLICINA":

        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value == e.FormattedValue)
            return;

        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["KOLICINA"].Value = e.FormattedValue;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRODAJNAVREDNOSTSAPOPUSTOM"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["KOLICINA"].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRODAJNACENASAPOPUSTOM"].Value);
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRODAJNAVREDNOST"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["KOLICINA"].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRODAJNACENA"].Value);
        PresaberiStavku(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex], false);
        break;
    case "RABAT":

        if (Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value) == Convert.ToDouble(M.String.LeaveOnlyNumbers(e.FormattedValue.ToString())))
            return;

        double r = Convert.ToDouble(M.String.LeaveOnlyNumbers(e.FormattedValue.ToString()));
        double k = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["KOLICINA"].Value);
        double pc = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRODAJNACENA"].Value);
        double pcsp = pc - (pc * r / 100);
        double pvsp = pcsp * k;

        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RABAT"].Value = r;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRODAJNACENASAPOPUSTOM"].Value = pcsp;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PRODAJNAVREDNOSTSAPOPUSTOM"].Value = pvsp;

        PresaberiStavku(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex], false);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When entering data in a cell which has formatting you should consider these facts:

- The value of cell remains untouched and formatting is for display purpose.
- When entering data in the cell you should enter data without any formatting,  For example having `0%` as `Format`, if you type `50%` as value, it's not valid, but `50` is valid and will be shown as `50%`.
- When entering data, if you don't change anything in the cell, `DataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty` returns `false`, otherwise it returns `true`.
- `e.FormattedValue` always contains the text which is displaying in the cell.

Knowing above facts, I believe you have enough information to complete what you are trying to do.

For example, knowing the cell is not dirty, you can return. Otherwise you need to check if `e.FormattedValue` can be converted to `ValueType` of the column. Keep in mind, typing `50%` in case that makes the cell dirty, is an invalid data.

Comment: When i type in value and move to next row/cell my `e.formattedvalue` is normal number without format, but when i just step on cell (do not enter edit mode) and move to the next cell it fire event and i get that `e.formattedvalue` is value with format.

Comment: Did you pay attention to `DataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty`? You can say `if(dataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty) return;`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `e.FormattedValue` with `decimal.Parse(e.FormattedValue.TrimEnd(new char[] { '%', ' ' })).ToString()`, and add a .ToString() to the end of `dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value` so it's like this `dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString()`.

The check should then read `if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString() == decimal.Parse(e.FormattedValue.TrimEnd(new char[] { '%', ' ' })).ToString())`

Comment: Read last sentence of my question. I already know that but what if my formatting style is `"0.#0 ROK -- BTW"`